# Full Control Over CD/DVD burning

Tags: compact-disc, burning

Suppose I want to burn **just** the 6000th byte(if thats not possible say the 10th sector) on a CDR without touching anyother region. Sounds possible but is there any tool to accomplish this.

Yeah sure, there may be no clear point doing this but is this possible technically?. 
(Doesnt matter maintaining the CDFS, integrity or whatever standard here. Just the task.)

It would be great to know if there are any software regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it should be possible, but I doubt that there's ready-made software for this (rather peculiar) task. A workaround might be to create an image from the source CD, edit the n-th byte (or sector) with a hex editor (e.g. hexer on Linux, [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/hxd/) on Windows, or [0xED](http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/0xed.html) on OSX), and then burn the image back to a new CD-R.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. That's a great idea! But suppose I want to write outside the image.. Say the disc has its filesystem in 400MB and I want to do some burning near the outer edge of the disc(in the spare 300MB region). But as @Hennes mentioned, its unclear whether firmware will let us do that.

Comment: That might be close enough to normal writing that a complex set of commands might allow that. E.g. grab a SCSI burner, write your own set of commands and send them via hdparm to a pass though device. (Assuming GNU/Linux environment. No idea how you do that under windows. And that is about the same as write your own software which was already Ansgars answer.)

Answer (score 0):

If the CD-R is already written then no. You can only write once to a CD-R.

If it has no yet been written (or is a CD-RW) then the question gets more interesting. I do not see any technical reason why it can't be done. However consumer CD burners do a lot from the firmware, and you might need to write your own firmware to support this. Which means that for a home user it is not feasible.

Comment: "consumer CD burners do a lot from the firmware" I guess this explains all of it.

If firmware is not blocking us, writting over a CD-R already written should be possible dont you think (true its not erasable, but still can burn the unburned region).

Comment: True. You should be able to write to an already written sector and make the result a unreadable mess. The same holds for individual bytes if the mechanism is precise enough. (I doubt it is that precise).